# Android studio "Cannot resolved symbol AppCompatActivity"

Tags: android, android-studio

When I open my old Android Project (it is working normally), It gives AppCompatActivity error.

After that I created a new project but it gives the same error.

[image]

This is my default grandle ;
[image]

I tried to change sdk version, change dependecies, invalidate caches, clean project..

I could not find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Check if in yout `gradle.properties` file you have this :

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

If is there, what I'm missing in your `gradle` file is the `buildToolsVersion` add this below the  `compileSdkVersion`

```
buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
```

Then repeat the steps you followed mentioned in your question.

Comment: Thank you for answer, I checked this lines in gradle.properties and I found that. Then I tried to add buildToolsVersion but still give error.

Comment: Could you upload the repository on Github and share it? I'd like to get more in detail

Comment: You can access on this link : https://github.com/tubakoseoglu/android-test

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use AndroidX but seems like it doesn't have the library, so you can simply try to migrate to AndroidX, go to:

**Refactor  -> Migrate to AndroidX ... -> Migrate**

[image: Migrate to AndroidX]

But if you don't want to migrate to AndroidX, remove the import statement and then let Android Studio import it for you.

1. Remove the import statement:

   import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
2. Focus your pointer on the **red lined** `AppCompatActivity` and press Alt+Enter and Android Studio will automatically import it for you.

[image: AppCompatActivity red lined]

Comment: Hi, thank you. I removed the import statement but it shows only androidx.appcompat. And I tried to convert to Androidx like you showed me, but it gives error ; "No usages found in the project"